# Get Base64 image dimension in python

Tags: python, base64, jpeg

Assuming one has a base64 encoded image.

**How can one extract the image dimensions from the string, preferably without storing the string to disc as an image?**

For PNG files, I can get this from bytes 16-24 of the string which are part of the PNG header, but for JPEG images, it appears no such hack exists.

What are some nice ways of getting the image dimensions in this case?

Comment: Have you got an example base64 image and perhaps looked at the pillow library?

Comment: @JonClements - Yep, I'll add an answer presently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the pillow library one can do:

```
import io
import PIL
from PIL import Image

imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64_str)
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
width, height = im.size
```

Comment: Was this meant to be a self-answered question all along? No worries if so - it's handy to know, but you do know that `import Image from PIL` is not valid? You're also not showing the import of the `base64` or `io` module...

Comment: @JonClements - No actually, and I didn't know that `import Image from PIL` isn't valid. why not?

Comment: @JonClements - me typing without thinking. Fixed, thanks!